# Why is this CSS rule being applied?

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I have a page that uses jQuery UI for tabs, and I noticed some weird behavior in the Chrome inspector. Here's a screenshot showing the hierarchy up to the element in question, and the CSS rule that is being applied to it.

The CSS rule should apply to elements with class `ui-widget-overlay`, but the selected element does not have that class. Furthermore, toggling the background and opacity properties in that rule off and back on actually changes the page (when it obviously shouldn't). Is it some weird inspector bug or am I missing something here? It seems that it erroneously displays the rule that is completely irrelevant to the selected element, and toggling the properties makes them apply to the element when they previously weren't.

[image]

Comment: What elements are inside of that one?

Comment: There's a lot of elements, but I can't see how that should make the inspector show the rule being applied to the parent element. Searching for `ui-widget-overlay` shows no results at all, so it should not be applied to *any* element on the page.

Comment: Can you set up a demo?

Comment: You're right, but it's hard to tell from just a screenshot. Can you copy and past the elements/css into a fiddle/jsbin for us?

Comment: It is a part of a working website so it might be hard to separate the relevant part, but you can see it in action on www.d3planner.com, meanwhile I'll try to make a fiddle.

Comment: I don't see the overlay style on that page, however, I don't see the theme-light class either

Comment: it may be applied by your javascript.. `$.dialog` will add that class afaik.

Comment: Oh the default theme is dark, but I see the same thing with both themes. It seems like a strange inspector bug to me, I don't see it in the latest Chrome either (I was using a different chromium-based browser before). Sorry for the confusion, I suppose.

Comment: @JFit: the inspector should show all dynamically added classes. As far as I can tell, there isn't a single element in the page with that class. I'm now convinced that it is some strange inspector bug in my browser version.

Comment: Which browser version did you see the problem with then.